# How is a question about the Eclipse IDE off-topic?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, specific-question, closed-questions

Why was this question about disabling plugins in Eclipse closed?  It falls within the domain of programming tools and besides it is quite useful: [Disable plugins on Eclipse startup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12677369/disable-plugins-on-eclipse-startup/12677509)

Comment: You're 100% correct. Voting to reopen.

Comment: I would have voted to close because of the error-message tease: *"It says "There was an error" or some such uninformative message."*. And the user didn't respond immediately to follow-up questions in comments. The answers would have either been guesses or debugging tips.

Comment: @MikeB That was my initial thought as well, though reading further it is easy to see that for the final question asked, the error message itself is not all that important. For question completeness though, it might still be nice to have it.

Comment: An excellent answer more than compensates for a poor question.  Questions can get edited into higher quality over time.  I wish more SO users used their administrative privileges to edit rather than to close.

Comment: @GarrettHall That's the difference between employees and volunteers. Volunteers are more inclined to throw away crap rather than trying to polish it.

Comment: @GarrettHall Closing is a way to raise a big red flag that says to all involved, "This question needs help!" It is, therefore, a way to try to *get it edited* to improve it. closing in no way prohibits subsequent editing. The two need not be conflated at all.

Comment: @AndrewBarber Exactly. I sometimes wish we could get that message across a bit better. I would prevent a lot of ranting.

Answer (score 11):

Besides it being poorly phrased and unnecessarily ranty (which I have now addressed), I think it is a fair enough question. As such I have voted to reopen it. I would say it falls well within the required parameters for a question about a software development tool.

Comment: The part about not recommending the plugin was not necessary, and the question is better now than it was before. If just the question would report the exact message, it would be more helpful to future readers. `:)`