# How can a question about IDE be off topic on SO?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, closed-questions, reopen-closed

Just wondering why my question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8934327/ide-for-sinatra-that-provides-list-of-routes was closed as off topic.

From the questions / answers below I understood that such questions 'are' ok on SO

- [What kind of questions about development tools are appropriate for Stack Overflow?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33036/what-kind-of-questions-about-development-tools-are-appropriate-for-stack-overflo)
- [How is a question about the Eclipse IDE off-topic?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/149107/how-is-a-question-about-the-eclipse-ide-off-topic)
- [Are questions about IDEs on topic?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/61726/are-questions-about-ides-on-topic)
- [Why is this question about Netbeans off-topic?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/155726/why-is-this-question-about-netbeans-off-topic)

So could some one make it clear for me what is 'wrong' with my question? How it could be 'improved' so it could be reopened? So I can learn and such situation won't happen to me again?

Comment: Your question isn't about working with an IDE, you are asking us to find an IDE for you. That's not really a programming question.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you're asking how to use a specific programming tool, that's fine.  Your question is asking for a recommendation for a tool.  That's a shopping list question.

Comment: Yes, but. It seems to me that such tool doesn't exist. So this cannot be confirmed by community? I did my research, installed few tools. So what's next I can do?

Comment: @Radek You can ask for recommendations in the chat rooms or on another site.

Comment: OK then, I thought that "shopping" isn't that black or white ...